# JQuery send data using div.find

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to write this correct:

```
var data = packageDiv.find('[name$=Code]').val();
var s = s + data;
packageDiv.find('[name$=Code]').val() = s;
```

I have got here problem:

```
packageDiv.find('[name$=Code]').val() = s;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
packageDiv.find('[name$=Code]').val(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
packageDiv.find('[name$=Code]').val(s);
```